# Javascript Loading a link on a new page from a function

Tags: javascript, location, href

```
function loadPage(list) {
    location.href=list.options[list.selectedIndex].value
}
```

I have a function, that loads from a list:

```
<form name="countrySelector" id="countrySelector">
        <select name="file" size="1" onchange="loadPage(this.form.elements[0])" target="_blank" onmouseclick="this.focus()">
            <option value="empty">Select</option>
            <option value="http://www.facebook.com/">Argentina</option>
```

Is there a way to force this function to open the link in a new window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function loadPage(list) { 
    window.open(list.options[list.selectedIndex].value);
}
```

Try it out [on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cYhqt/). Be warned that it might trigger the user's popup blocker.

Comment: It won't trigger a browser's default popup blocker since the window is triggered by a user action.

Comment: @PaulPRO It triggers my browser's (IE9) default popup blocker.

Comment: Oh weird, I didn't think it would... Does this trigger it too? http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/sybd9/

Comment: It doesn't trigger on links with a `_blank` target, no. Your example works in Chrome, but it doesn't seem to work in Firefox or IE9

Comment: I guess that means Firefox and IE9 don't consider onchange to be a user action. In that case the OP might be out of luck if he wants to avoid a popup blocker.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`window.open`](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml):

```
function loadPage(list) {
    window.open(list.options[list.selectedIndex].value, "WindowName");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function loadPage(list){
    var href = list.options[list.selectedIndex].value;
    var features = 'scrollbars=no,menubar=no,height=600,width=800,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no';

    window.open(href,'WindowName', features);
}
```

more info [here](http://www.web-source.net/javascript_popup_window2.htm) and [here](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml)